# Using Java Commercially

Tags: java

I am currently in the process of writing some software in Java that I may one day decide to sell online. I am using the Java SE library. Do I have to pay any licensing feels to Oracle if I plan to sell this, because with the recent news of Oracle suing Google I am concerned for the future of this platform.

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are free to sell Java software without any licensing issues. The Oracle/Google lawsuit is specifically about Google's alleged breaches of several Oracle patents, which are all to do with JVM implementation details. If you're writing software to run ON the JVM, you don't have an issue. For more info on the lawsuit, see the [lengthy blogpost by Charles Nutter](http://blog.headius.com/2010/08/my-thoughts-on-oracle-v-google.html).

Obviously, though, IANAL.

Answer (score 1):

From my remembrances, it seems to me that, as long as you don't ship a Java VM with your product (but rather explain to your users how to download it from Oracle), you won't have any issues.

Comment: So either distribute the jar file or use the webstart? Compiling everything into an exe is not okay?

Comment: I can be wrong, but I think that distributing the JRE is allowed, too.

Comment: License file within the JRE folder: "Sun grants you a [...] license without fees to reproduce and distribute the Software (except for the JavaFX Runtime), provided that (i) you distribute the Software complete and unmodified and only bundled as part of, and for the sole purpose of running, your Programs [...]"

Answer (score 0):

If you read the news carefully, you'll soon realize, that the lawsuit is limited to googles Dalvik virtual machine which is used on Android. Unless you plan to develop applications for Android in Java (or any other platform, that is limited to use a virtual machine which isn't licensed by Oracle), you don't have to worry at all.

And even if, I don't see any risk, that Dalvik will be removed from all handhelds as a result from this fight.